# No module named 'commons'

Tags: python, machine-learning

Trabajando con **Chefboost**, para construir un árbol de decisión, usando el algoritmo `c4.5`, me encuentro con este error

> "No module named 'commoms'"

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

```
import chefboost.Chefboost as chef
import chefboost.commons
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data_set_train.csv")
print(df.head())

config = {'algorithm':'C4.5'}
model = chef.fit(df.copy(), config)

feature = df.iloc[0]
prediction = chef.predict(model, feature)
print(prediction)
```

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta pues estás en SO en español

Answer (score 0):

Update: import Chefboost as chef es necesario, de lo contrario puede tirar un error distinto.

Agrega esto al inicio de tu código:

```
import Chefboost as chef
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("dataset/golf.txt") #Tu dataset

config = {'algorithm': 'ID3'}
model = chef.fit(df, config)
```

No estoy seguro si funciona. Nos comentas el resultado.